# AngularJs ng-repeat of objects orderBy object-id in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to order the result of an `ng-repeat` of objects by his specific object "id". This order is in an array so i made this custom filter `ng-repeat="line in dataObject|objectIdFilter:orderByArray"`:

```
.filter('objectIdFilter', [function() {
    return function(inputObjet, orderArray) {
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(orderArray, function(value) {
          result.push(inputObjet[value]);
        });
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }
}])
```

And that's an example basic controller with the objects and the order id in an array:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.dataObject = {
    1: {username:'user1'},
    10: {username:'user10'},
    20: {username:'user20'},
    500: {username:'user500'}
  };

  $scope.orderByArray = [20,10,1,500];

}])
```

With his HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="line in dataObject|objectIdFilter:orderByArray">{{line.username}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/infnadanada/tLrx4uro/

so...

- **All is working Ok** but i don't know if there is another way to order the ng-repeat like i did without using a custom filter.
- As well if you go to the Jsfiddle in the browser console you can see how my custom filter is returning 2 times the result and i don't know why.

PD: English is not my 1st language :D

Thanks

Comment: See for your second problem  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/databinding-in-angularjs

Comment: @intekhab is for datbinding problem? `apply`'s `diggest`'s..? So it's an angularjs native problem? Can i do something to solve that?

Comment: I would create js function in controller to do the same as your filter 'objectIdFilter' does, and call it once, because filter getting called every time you do something with collection.

Comment: ok i see. You guys are right, i can do the same and clear the html template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be another good approach but you can filter your data inside your controller without using filter. By using this you can prevent angular to calling the filter twice.

```
$scope.dataObject = {
    1: {username:'user1'},
    10: {username:'user10'},
    20: {username:'user20'},
    500: {username:'user500'}
  };
  $scope.orderByArray = [20,10,1,500];
   $scope.result = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.orderByArray, function(value) {
      $scope.result.push($scope.dataObject[value]);
  });
}]);
```

Inside the template

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="line in result">{{line.username}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way: you can iterate through `map`: https://jsfiddle.net/sherali/tLrx4uro/2/

```
$scope.dataObject = {
    1: {username:'user1'},
    10: {username:'user10'},
    20: {username:'user20'},
    500: {username:'user500'}
  };
  $scope.orderByArray = [20,10,1,500];
  $scope.result = $scope.orderByArray.map(function(value){
      return $scope.dataObject[value];
  });
```

Comment: it's a valid answer but i searched a little what can be better and i found http://jsperf.com/map-foreach i don't know if that can be valid for `angular.forEach` i will investigate a bit more :D Thanks

Comment: @nada. Thanks for above link. I didn't know

Comment: also, i researched above foreach(angular and native). I found that: https://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-vs-native-for-loop/3

Comment: `angular.forEach(arr...)` is faster than `arr.forEach(...)`